# How to detect move start Carousel View Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I trying implement detecting move start CarouselView Xamarin.Forms.
But, CarouselView only have type of move end EventHandlers... e.g. ItemSelected

Please tell me how to detect move start CarouselView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source [1] there is no built in event to do this. You could probably do this with a custom renderer [2], though it is likely not trivial.

[1] https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/blob/master/txt/src/carouselView/dev/Shared/CarouselView.cs
[2] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/